# start from first route of InitialRouteStack

Tags: routes, react-native, navigator

How to start from first route of InitialRouteStack?

I need it without `jumpTo` animation. When I use InitialRouteStack — it moves me to the last route.

Answer (score 0):

Providing a route stack would be for when you want the user to start with ability to "move back" through the stack already. I would recommend using initialRoute which is a single route object which would have you end up on that route and the user can navigate from there with pushes to the navigator object.

See: https://rnplay.org/apps/p5CTSQ